# What is the best approach to images with changing hue?

Tags: java, performance, image-processing, bufferedimage

I have a completely desaturated `BufferedImage` in Java that I need to display to a JFrame many times a second, however, the image needs to be saturated with a certain hue before being rendered. The problem I am facing is that I don't know any approach that is fast enough performance wise to be able to give a smooth frame rate whilst the hue changes each frame.

I have tried to generate an image with the desired hue value during the rendering pass, but that gives a slow frame rate unless the image is quite small. I have also tried to cache a bunch of saturated images and choose one for each frame, but with just 256 cached images it creates very long load times.

The image is likely to be around `1000x500` pixels in size.

The code I currently have to recolor the image is the following:

```
private BufferedImage recolored(BufferedImage image, float hue) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
    BufferedImage res = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    WritableRaster resRast = res.getRaster();

    for (int xx = 0; xx < width; xx++) {
        for (int yy = 0; yy < height; yy++) {
            Color color = new Color(Color.HSBtoRGB(hue, 0.7f, 0.7f));

            int[] pixels = raster.getPixel(xx, yy, (int[]) null);
            pixels[0] = color.getRed();
            pixels[1] = color.getGreen();
            pixels[2] = color.getBlue();
            resRast.setPixel(xx, yy, pixels);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

So, my question is:

- What is the standard, generally accepted or best way in order to display an image with a constantly changing hue?
- Is it reasonable to do so with an image of my size?

Also, I doubt that it matters, but the hue is changing in a linearly over time and wraps back to zero after overflowing. Basically it cycles through all colors and then repeats.

Comment: 1) don't ask for "best" things. best says nothing and means something different to everyone.  2) if you want something fast you need to specify what "many times per second" means and what machine you are running the software on...

Comment: @Piglet Thanks, I will try to do this in future.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is not very specific I will point out a few flaws in your code. If you fix these you should see a reasonable improvement in speed.

You have a function that takes a BufferedImage and a Hue value as input.

```
for (int xx = 0; xx < width; xx++) {
    for (int yy = 0; yy < height; yy++) {
        Color color = new Color(Color.HSBtoRGB(hue, 0.7f, 0.7f));

        int[] pixels = raster.getPixel(xx, yy, (int[]) null);
        pixels[0] = color.getRed();
        pixels[1] = color.getGreen();
        pixels[2] = color.getBlue();
        resRast.setPixel(xx, yy, pixels);
    }
}
```

In this nested loop you iterate over every pixel in the image. For every coordinate in your image you calculate a rgb color from the provided hue value.

You then read a pixel from your input image, change its colors and then set that color to a pixel in your output image.

All this function does is fill an image with a certain hue.

- You read width * height pixels without using their information.
- You calculate an RBG colour width * height times althought it's the same
  for every pixel
- You read that colors RGB values 3 * height * width times
- You assign these values 3 * height * width times.

All you needed to do is calculate a single RGB touple once outside your loop. Then set every pixel in your output image to that values.